# Question answered but a new issue appeared

Tags: discussion

I have asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309416/min-height-css-issue-when-using-angularjs-routing), and Bhojendra Nepal correctly answered to it, meaning that the issue was solved.
I have created the code for the question outside the main website project, because I didn't want to use unnecessary code. After I solved it in the project as well, a new issue come out (as a result of the modifications). I have edited the question, but Bhojendra Nepal couldn't help me anymore.

My questions are:

1. Should I accept his answer, now that he couldn't solve the new issue for me?
2. If so, should I make a new question with the second issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't have added the new question to the old one in the first place.

If a new problem pops up, ask a new question.
You can link to the previous one to provide some context.

My suggestion would be to revert the edits on your question, returning to it's original state, accepting the answer, and then to ask a new question about your new problem.

Comment: Agreed.  If an answer answers the question, the community is better served by accepting the answer than by amending the question to include a follow-on.